# Python, next element to array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I need to access the next element of an array to compare it with the previous one, try to do it by indexes however the index is out of range

```
lista =  [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8]
for i in range(len(lista)):
if lista[i]==lista[i+1]: print("same number")
```

Comment: you should use ```len(lista)-1``` since the last element has no next

Comment: What is the maximum value that `i` will be assigned here? If it is out of range of `lista`, then perhaps change the loop so that it never has a value greater than the largest index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can zip the list with itself offset by one and avoid the indices altogether:

```
lista =  [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8]
for a, b in zip(lista, lista[1:]):
    if a == b: 
        print("same number", a, b)
```

Prints:

> same number 2 2
>   same number 5 5

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the size of the list before doing the process. check the code bellow

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
if i == len(lista)-1:
    print("end Process")
else:
    a = lista[i]
    b = lista[i+1]
    if a == b:
        print( str(a) + " and " + str(b) + " are the same number ")
```

or using len(lista)-1 in your for loop

```
for i in range(len(lista)-1):
        a = lista[i]
        b = lista[i+1]
        if a == b:
            print( str(a) + " and " + str(b) + " are the same number ")
```